# Multidimensional Array for students and grades

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am not sure if multidimensional arrays would be the correct thing for what I want to do.

I want to input the amount of students and then for each of them I input 5 grades. After doing so I must calculate the average.

So essentially something like this:

> Student..........Grade 1......Grade 2......Grade 3......Grade 4......Grade 5......Average
>
> Student1............87..............71................64...............89...............78..............77.8
>
> Student2............54..............76................89...............89...............78..............77.2

I apologise for the formatting. I don't know block quotes to well.
I am not sure if multidimensional arrays would help. Any Ideas.

Answer (score 0):

what you can do is to create a Student class and make an array of Student e.g.

```
public class Student
{
    private ArrayList grades;

    public Student()
    {
        grades = new ArrayList();
    }

    public void addGrade(double val)
    {
        grades.Add(val);
    }

    public double getAverage()
    {
        double avg = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < grades.Count; i++)
            avg += (double)grades[i];

        avg /= grades.Count;
        return avg;
    }
}
```

and make an array of Student class as:

```
Student [] students = new Student[10];
```

add student grades as:

```
students[0].addGrade(75);
```

Comment: Thanks so much. How do I allow the user to input grades and store them in the list

Comment: if you have GUI then use textboxes for user input. For console application use `Console.ReadLine`.

Answer (score 0):

Since the `datatype` of a student's name is probably a `string` and the `datatype` of a student's grades is probably a list of `double`, I recommend you start with a `class` that represents a single student. Then, as you gather one student's data from a form, you can create a student `object`, load the `object` with data from a form, then calculate the average grade for the student. I'm not sure if you need to do anything with the student `object` after that (i.e., add it to a list for export, write it to a database, etc., etc.)

The code below only suggests what the student class might look like.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace sandbox
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }

    class Student
    {
        string studentFirstMiddleLastName;
        IList<double> allStudentGrades = new List<double>();

        public Student(string studentFirstMiddleLastName, IList<double> allStudentGrades)
        {
            StudentFirstMiddleLastName = studentFirstMiddleLastName;
            AllStudentGrades = allStudentGrades;
        }

        public string StudentFirstMiddleLastName { get => studentFirstMiddleLastName; set => studentFirstMiddleLastName = value; }
        public IList<double> AllStudentGrades { get => allStudentGrades; set => allStudentGrades = value; }

        public double CalculateAverageofAllStudentGrades()
        {
            double average = 0.0;

            // add up all grades in AllStudentGrades, divide by number of items in AllStudentGrades, load result of this calculation into the variable `average`

            return average;
        }
    }
}
```